# How to copy from current position to the end of line in vi

Tags: vim, vi

I use gvim in windows. How do I copy text from the current position to the end of the line in vi and paste it in another file opened in vi?

Comment: do `y$` in normal mode

Answer (score 198, accepted):

The normal-mode command to move to the end of the line is `$`.

You can copy to the end of the line with `y$` and paste with `p`.

To copy/paste between different instances, you can use the system clipboard by selecting the `*` register, so the commands become `"*y$` for copying and `"*p` for pasting.

`$` move-to-linebreak

<kbd>$</kbd>

**`y$` yank-to-linebreak**

<kbd>y</kbd>,<kbd>$</kbd>

`"*y$` select clipboard-register yank-to-linebreak

<kbd>"</kbd>,<kbd>*</kbd>,<kbd>y</kbd>,<kbd>$</kbd>

`"*p` select clipboard-register paste

<kbd>"</kbd>,<kbd>*</kbd>,<kbd>p</kbd>

Check `:h registers` for more information.

Comment: Thanks. but i want to paste the contents to 'another file' opened in vi. This works with same file only.

Comment: It will work for any file open within the same instance. You can copy to system clipboard by selecting the `*` (or `+`) register.

Comment: Why the system registers can't work... I can't copy the context in `file1` to `file2`. I still need to use the mouse. What could be the reason probably?

Comment: I usually use `D` to cut from current position to the end and `p` to paste(recover) the original data, and then move to somewhere else to paste the yanked data. Simply because it is far easier to type `D` than `y$`.

Comment: @neevek Came here to find a better solution to `Dp` ... was disappointed.

Comment: :y$ only copies one character.

Comment: @PhilipRego, it's `y$`, without semicolon.

Answer (score 61):

If you don't want to include the line break with the yank, you can use `yg_`. (Or in your case, `"*yg_`)

Basically, just recognize there's a difference between `$` and `g_` movement-wise. It's helped me on numerous occasions.

Comment: Is there anyway to swap `g_` and `$`? I find myself rarely if ever needing to include the line break in motions.

Comment: YES!  the extra newline is driving me crazy.  This is the info needed.

Comment: @JonathanDumaine in your `$MYVIMRC` add the line `nmap $ g_`

Comment: @thedanotto you beautiful person

Answer (score 12):

Add this line to your .vimrc

```
" Make Y yank till end of line
nnoremap Y y$
```

More at [my vimrc](https://github.com/AndrewRayCode/configs/blob/master/.vimrc).

Comment: @KhalilRavanna True but isn't that already covered by `yy`?

Comment: @KhalilRavanna You just got done saying that the default functionality of `Y` yanks the whole line, start to end (in your previous comment). `Y` does not yank from the cursor to the end of the line unless you remap it as suggested by this answer.

Comment: Lol you're right I checked this comment without thinking and had internalized this suggestion somehow. Going to delete all these comments to remove possible confusion for future users. I recommend you do the same. Thanks for correcting my momentary stupidity :)

Answer (score 3):

A different solution: `Dp` and paste it with `p`. In fact this first deletes to the end of line and re-pastes it at the same location. Paste it somewhere else with `p`.

Comment: Why not Du and leave the file unmodified? (note: this include new line)