# Yank from current cursor position till end of line

Tags: vim

I tried using `Y` to yank until end of line, but that just imitates `yy`, I searched this up, and some people seem to say that that's the intended behavior, however, the Vim cheat sheet (https://vim.rtorr.com/), and the fact that `D` and `C` "delete" and "change" till end of line, tells me otherwise. Is the cheat sheet outdated? Why is `Y` so special that it breaks the pattern that `D` and `C` follow? Now I know that I can remap `Y` to `y$` like this:

```
nnoremap Y y$
```

Still, however, the fact that I have to do that, and that's not the default behavior seems to be completely counter-intuitive and does not make sense to me. If there's a good reason for this I would love to know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy from current position to the end of line in vi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764176/how-to-copy-from-current-position-to-the-end-of-line-in-vi)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+yank+end+of+line

Comment: Esp. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45536949/7976758

Comment: Thanks, not sure why that question is so far down the search, it helps with the mapping, but would be nice to know why `Y` does what it does in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So… the canonical way to "yank from cursor to end of line" is:

```
y$
```

where:

- `y` is an `:help operator`, `help y`,
- and `$` is the motion on which it operates, `:help $`.

You can also do `c$` to "change from cursor to end of line" or `d$` to "delete from cursor to end of line", etc.

That form, "operator+motion", is reasonably certain to work in vi itself and lots of its clone/emulators, including Vim in all its incarnations. It is all very logical and intuitive.

The troubles started with vi, which had `C`, an alternative to `c$`, and `D`, an alternative to `d$`, but not `Y`, which is only one of *many* inconsistencies.

As a vi impersonator, Vim had to maintain compatibility with vi. Concretely, it meant that it couldn't change the semantics of old vi commands—so `c`, `d`, `y`, `$`, `C`, and `D` had to stay the same—but it also meant that it was free to create *new* commands. And creating new commands it did, like `Y`. Logically, it *should* have been made to work like `y$`, but the author decided against all common sense to make it work like `yy` instead.

If you come from `c$` and `d$`, then `Y` is weird. If you come from `yy`, `cc`, and `dd`, then it is `C` and `D` that are weird. So much for that famous "Vim language".

Because that is nonsense lots of users have been adding variants of the mapping below to their `vimrc`s for literally decades, possibly even in vi:

```
nmap Y y$
```

as per `:help Y`. Which led to the current status quo: OK, `Y` is `yy` out of the box, but fixing it to be `y$` is an easy one-time fix so *whatever*.

Don't get me started on freaking `cw`.